# Unable to open renamed image

Tags: linux, opencv

I am having a rather strange problem.

I'm trying to open the last modified image with :

```
std::string exec(string cmd) {
FILE* pipe = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
char buffer[128];
std::string result = "";

if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
result = buffer;

pclose(pipe);
result[strlen(result.c_str()) - 1] = '\0';
return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    string s = exec("ls ./images -1t | tail -1 &> text.txt");
    Mat img = imread(s);
    imshow("image", img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0; 
}
```

This piece of code works fine. But whenever I rename the file and run this code, the `imshow` part crashes saying the image has size 0. When I try to print the file name, I get it correct in both cases.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What is the orignal filename and the one you're renaming to?

Comment: doesn't matter whatever I try, I am having the same issue. Just FYI, it was line12.jpg, and renamed it to line15.jpg (and many more combinations)

Comment: Is anyone else having the same issues after trying out the code?

Comment: Your code as-is isn't "credible", the command you execute does not produce any output (unless an error happens). And it would try to open a file in the wrong directory (would try to open it in the current directory instead of `./images`). So it can't really work. You've probably got a file both in your current directory and in images that has the same name.

Comment: Sorry about that. My directory structure is as follows : the text.txt is in the same folder as the executable. And the ./images folder holds the images. Maybe you can try to modify the path to suit your directory structure

Comment: I repeat: The command you're executing does not return any output if it doesn't fail. The code you posted cannot possibly work. Some variations of it might have worked, but what you have up there cannot.

Comment: I do not understand why it won't. I am using it since yesterday. Only when I tried to rename the file name, I had the issue.

Comment: `... tail -1 &> text.txt`. <- all the output of ls goes to that file. The problem about the paths generated even if you didn't have that redirection would remain, i.e. you're missing adding ./images/ to the path you'd be getting back from ls if you were getting it.

Comment: Now I got your point! And it works. How can I accept your answer?

Comment: @Mat has to repost it below